# How to disable Code Rearrangement for part of code in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

I often use code rearrangement in Android Studio and it's working well for me with one exception. When I use `@interface`, it moves it away from my constants. I tried to use `//@formatter:off` and `//@formatter:on` markers for disabling rearrangement but it's no good.

**CODE SAMPLE:**

```
    // @formatter:off
    @IntDef({A, B})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface CommandType {}
    public static final byte A = 0;
    public static final byte B = 1;
    // @formatter:on
```

Is it possible to turn of rearrangement for a code part? Or is there a way how to set rearrangement rules to ignore `@interface`?